# No entiendo la sintaxis ni funcionamiento de este bucle

Tags: c++, bucle-for, archivo, bucles

¿podría alguien explicar la sintaxis de este bucle for y cómo funciona?
He intentado entenderlo depurando el código pero no acabo de aclararme.

La idea fundametal del código es que recorra el fichero especificado y vaya guardando los datos por columnas en tres vectores distintos que corresponderían con unas coordenadas (x,y,z).

```
std::vector<float> x_coord, y_coord, z_coord;

for (std::ifstream o{"FAU.cube"}; o;){
   float dato;

   if (o >> dato)
      numeros1.push_back(numero);
   if (o >> dato)
      numeros2.push_back(numero);
   if (o >> dato)
      numeros3.push_back(numero);
 }
```

Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un `for` define:

- lista de inicializaciones
- una expresión booleana
- lista de instrucciones a ejecutar al final del bucle.

Solo la expresión booleana es obligatoria.

Aquí tienes un `for` que crea un objeto `ifstream` en la variable `o`, y que en cada iteración invoca [el operador bool de ifstream](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) para comprobar si puede seguir leyendo del stream. La tercera lista de expresiones no aparece.

Aquí, leyendo la documentación, me da la sensación de que este operador no devolverá *null* (es decir, *false*) si se llega al fin del fichero, así que igual no funciona como se espera. En todo caso hace tiempo que no toco C++ y no lo puedo asegurar al 100%.

Luego, dentro del bucle, simplemente usa el operador `>>` para leer datos del *stream*.

Comment: y que es ```{"FAU.cube"}```?

Comment: @Srsole una forma de invocar el constructor https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization